# HWIOAuthBundle, Facebook & Apache Reverse Proxy does not work

Tags: symfony, facebook-php-sdk, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, facebook-authentication

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle with FosUserBundle on Symfony 2.3 to connect users with their facebook account.  It all works fine with a simple webserver setup (i.e. example.com).

The problem arises when I introduce a reverse proxy setup with the symfony2 app now being served on a subdirectory i.e. example.com/app).  I've followed the implementation of HWIOAuthBundle as here https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 and I use the javascript from the official documentation to create the button to connect to Facebook.

In the reverse proxy scenario, the authentication and connection dialogue with FB works as expected, but when you are returned back to the reverse proxy app, the Facebook session data can't be read by the web server behind the proxy (the app does not "see" any of the fb authentication data).

My question is: is there a problem with my proxy setup (configs below) or does the HWIOAuthBundle (or FB php-sdk) not work in this scenario without modification?

The vhost config for the proxy server is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.followthatfund.com/web
    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access_log common

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /app/ http://app.example.com/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://app.example.com /app/
    <Location /app/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /app/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app/ /
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the config for the app server is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app.example.com/current/web
    ServerName app.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app.example.com-access_log common
    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*) app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```